# VB.NET GetObject("winmgmts with late binding

Tags: vb.net, wmi

I am trying my best not to use late binding with the getObject function. How ever i know i wont be looked down upon turning strict off in only One class.

My question is i can't find what to declare my member type of.

```
         Dim restPoint = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\default:Systemrestore")

    If restPoint IsNot Nothing Then

        If restPoint.CreateRestorePoint("test restore point system", 12, 100) = 0 Then
            MsgBox("Restore Point created successfully")
        Else
            MsgBox("Could not create restore point!")
        End If
    End If
```

I have spent hours trying to research msdn createrestorepoint come from. I don't want to use WMI directly or keep strict off.

Thanks

Comment: are you asking about `restpoint`?

Comment: Apologies, I missed the "I don't want to use WMI", but for the record, Strict Off _is_ bad coding. There is nothing you can do with it off that you can't do with it on. If you disagree, I invite you to give me some links to prove me wrong

Comment: jmcilhinney, probably One of the best vbcoders around. A MVP for god knows how may years http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?661439-%93Option-strict-on-disallows-late-binding-quot-error

 Joacim Andersson the owner of vbofurms http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?682611-RESOLVED-error-Option-Strict-On-disallows-late-binding&p=4190245&viewfull=1#post4190245

strict off for ONE class in a project with it on is not bad.

Answer (score 0):

I guess i will go with WMI for now. That snippet cleaned up.

```
Imports System.Management

Public Class CreateRestorePoint

''' <summary>
''' Defines the search query for the ManagementScope path.
''' </summary>
Private Const MANAGEMENT_SCOPE As String = "\\localhost\root\default:SystemRestore"

''' <summary>
''' Attempts to create a new restore point using WMI.
''' </summary>
''' <returns>True if the restore point was created, other wise false.</returns>
''' <remarks>
''' Gets the object containing the input parameters to a method, and then fills in the values and passes the object to the InvokeMethod call.
''' </remarks>
Friend Function CreateRestorePoint() As Boolean

    Dim created As Boolean = True

    Using wmiQuery As New ManagementClass(New ManagementPath(MANAGEMENT_SCOPE))

        Dim query = GetParams(wmiQuery)

        Try
            wmiQuery.InvokeMethod("CreateRestorePoint", query, Nothing)
        Catch ex As ManagementException
            created = False
        End Try

    End Using

    Return created

End Function

''' <summary>
''' Sets the ManagementBaseObject parameters.
''' </summary>
''' <param name="wmiQuery"></param>
''' <returns>Returns a ManagementBaseObject representing the list of input parameters for a method.</returns>
''' <remarks>The members of this class enable you to access WMI data using a specific WMI class path.></remarks>
Private Function GetParams(wmiQuery As ManagementClass) As ManagementBaseObject

    Dim query = wmiQuery.GetMethodParameters("CreateRestorePoint")

    query("Description") = "-CautionSparta"
    query("RestorePointType") = 12
    query("EventType") = 100

    Return query

End Function

End Class
```